# Date format conversion to text (yyyymmdd)

Tags: python, date, text, types, format

I have a date in format of YYYY-MM-DD (2022-11-01). I want to convert it to 'YYYYMMDD' format (without hyphen). Pls support.

I tried this...

df['ConvertedDate']= df['DateOfBirth'].dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')... but no luck

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the format mask you should be using with `strftime` is `%Y%m%d`:

```py
df["ConvertedDate"] = df["DateOfBirth"].dt.strftime('%Y%m%d')
```

Comment: I am getting below error...

Comment: AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values

Comment: What is the type of the `DateOfBirth` column?  Is it text?

Answer (score 0):

Pandas itself providing the ability to convert strings to datetime in Pandas dataFrame with desire format.

```
df['ConvertedDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateOfBirth'], format='%Y-%m-%d').dt.strftime('%Y%m%d')
```

**Referenced Example:**

```
import pandas as pd

values = {'DateOfBirth': ['2021-01-14', '2022-11-01', '2022-11-01']}

df = pd.DataFrame(values)
df['ConvertedDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateOfBirth'], format='%Y-%m-%d').dt.strftime('%Y%m%d')

print (df)
```

**Output:**

```
  DateOfBirth ConvertedDate
0  2021-01-14      20210114
1  2022-11-01      20221101
2  2022-11-01      20221101
```

Comment: Got this error message ...

ValueError: time data '2021-01-14' does not match format '%Y%m%d' (match)

Comment: I've updated the answer, please try @Tarun

Comment: I'm expecting df['DateOfBirth'] is string value

Comment: Still getting the same error ...


ValueError: time data '2021-01-14' does not match format '%Y%m%d' (match)

Comment: just change the format

Comment: @Tarun - can you provide one example of the input value?

Comment: Here is the sample date ... 2021-01-14

Comment: @Tarun - Just try this one df['ConvertedDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateOfBirth'], format='%Y-%m-%d').dt.strftime('%Y%m%d')

Answer (score -1):

This works

```
from datetime import datetime 

initial = "2022-11-01"
time = datetime.strptime(initial, "%Y-%m-%d")
print(time.strftime("%Y%m%d"))
```

Comment: The OP seems to be using Pandas rather than core Python.

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't notice

Comment: This is working... but when I replace the InitialDate with Dataframe column I am getting the below error message... 
...

TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not Series

Comment: Maybe try to use series.to_string()

Comment: HI Shadowcrafter_01, I am fairly new to Python ... please help me how to use series.to_string() method.

Comment: I don't even know if that would work properly. I don't use Pandas. But you said you changed InitialDate do the Dataframe column. Call the to_string() method on that column